# Java - Convert a Tree to a Lists of Nodes with same depth

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to write a code to convert a binary tree to a lists of nodes with same depth. If a tree has depth d, then d lists will be created. The logic is to do in-order traversal and add the currently traversed node to the list of appropriate depth.

```
public void treeToListofNodesByLevel(Node<T> n,int depth, ArrayList<LinkedList<Node<T>>> treeList){

        if(n.right != null){
            inOrderWithHeight(n.right, depth + 1);
        }
        if(treeList.size() >= depth){
            treeList.add(depth, new LinkedList<Node<T>>() );
        }
        treeList.get(depth).add(n);
        if(n.left != null){
            inOrderWithHeight(n.left, depth + 1);
        }

    }
```

and then calling:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Node<T>>> result = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Node<T>>>();
treeToListofNodesByLevel(root, 0, result);
```

Will this work ? Are there any corner cases I am not handling ?
Also, right now I am passing the List of List to be returned by the method because I can not think of a way to initialize it in the method and returning it at then end while also maintaining the recursive structure. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: A complete binary tree with a height of 4 will have 8 different possible paths.  In this case, how would the lists look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the general concept pretty much perfect. It will work, and should handle all cases.

However, you have a few errors in the details:

- Your check for when to add a new list has the comparison in the wrong direction. It should be `if (treeList.size() <= depth)`.
- Each call to `inOrderWithHeight()` (which you haven't provided any code of) should be a recursive call to `treeToListofNodesByLevel()`. Keep the first two arguments as they are, and just pass the `treeList` for the third.
- This one's more a style issue, but parameter types should generally be declared as the highest level type that satisfies what you actually need. There is no need here to specify `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, any `List` will do. Change the `treeList` parameter's type to `List<List<Node<T>>>`.

For the matter of initializing the List inside the method while also using recursion, that's the sort of thing that implementation helper methods are for. Take the current body of `treeToListofNodesByLevel` and move it into a private method (with the recursive calls changed so the private method calls itself), let's call it `treeToListofNodesByLevelHelper`. Then change the current public method to this:

```
public List<List<Node<T>>> treeToListofNodesByLevel(Node<T> node) {
    List<List<Node<T>>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    treeToListofNodesByLevelHelper(node, 0, result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what the method "inOrderWithHeight" is doing. What I do for this question (not optimized) is to traverse like BFS using two queues and for each iteration adding the nodes of that depth to the list of that iteration (each iteration is traversing one depth of the tree).  Here is my code to do that for a binary tree as you supposed in your answer:

```
Queue<Node<T>> queue1 = new LinkedList<Node<T>>() ;
Queue<Node<T>> queue2 = new LinkedList<Node<T>>() ;
public void treeToListofNodesByLevel(Node<T> root, ArrayList<LinkedList<Node<T>>> treeList) {
    if (root == null)
        return;
    int curr_depth = 0;
    queue1.add(root);
    while(!queue1.isEmpty()){
        treeList.add(curr_depth, new LinkedList<Node<T>>());
        while(!queue1.isEmpty()){
            Node<T> node = queue1.remove();
            treeList.get(curr_depth).add(node);
            if(node.left != null) queue2.add(node.left);
            if(node.right != null) queue2.add(node.right);
        }
        curr_depth++;
        while(!queue2.isEmpty()){
            Node<T> node = queue2.remove();
            queue1.add(node);
        }    
    }
}
```

I wrote this on the fly without syntax checking and may have compiler errors. But hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Almost there... note that you only add a new `LinkedList` to `treeList` for `currDepth==0`, so you'll need another `add` for other depths.

Answer (score 0):

Why you just use the same function the code will be more beautifull :

```
    public void treeToListofNodesByLevel(BinaryTree node, int currentDepth, List<List<BinaryTree>> result){

    // Check if the list for the currentDepth is created
    if(result.get(currentDepth) != null){
        result.add(currentDepth, new ArrayList<BinaryTree>())
    }

    // Add the current node to the list
    result.get(currentDepth).add(node);


    // Recursive the left node
    if(node.left != null){
        treeToListofNodesByLevel(node.left, currentDepth+1, result);
    } 

    // Recursive the right node
    if(node.right != null){
        treeToListofNodesByLevel(node.right, currentDepth+1, result);
    }
}
```

In your main function :

```
List<List<BinaryTree>> result = new ArrayList<>();
BinaryTree root = new BinaryTree();  
treeToListofNodesByLevel(root, 0, result);
```